# error installing DBD::MySQL on osx 10.11 - Can't link/include C library '', aborting

Tags: mysql, macos, perl, homebrew, dbd

After updating perl via homebrew, i broke my `dbd::mysql` installation
installing via `cpanm` results in:

```
I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

    cflags        (mysql_config) = -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-
    c/6.1.9/include
    embedded      (guessed     ) =
    ldflags       (guessed     ) =
    libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-
    c/6.1.9/lib -l
    mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
    nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
    nofoundrows   (default     ) = 0
    nossl         (default     ) = 0
    testdb        (default     ) = test
    testhost      (default     ) =
    testpassword  (default     ) =
    testport      (default     ) =
    testsocket    (default     ) =
    testuser      (guessed     ) = root

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and 'perldoc DBD::mysql::INSTALL'.

Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Can't link/include C library '', aborting.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve?
I've tried removing `mysql-connector-c` and installing `mysql` via
homebrew instead. The complaint then is `Can't link/include C library
'ssl', 'crypto', aborting`. I do have `openssl` installed.

perl version:

```
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for
darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but I just had this problem installing DBD::mysql and I see that others are still having this problem too. Here's the convoluted solution that worked for me.

I started by running (MacOX Mojave 10.14.1):

- `brew install mysql`
- `cpanm install DBD::mysql`
- This fails.

This gave me the error message "Can't link/include C library 'ssl', 'crypto', aborting". As per [this thread](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=120810) and the DBD::mysql install instructions on meta-cpan, this error is happening because the DBD::mysql package requires (?) "mysql-connector-c" rather than "mysql". Okay, I fixed that by doing:

- `brew unlink mysql`
- `brew install mysql-connector-c`
- `cpanm install DBD::mysql`
- The cpan install still fails, but new error!

That "fixed" the issue in that it got me a different error message. I was now getting the message: "Can't link/include C library'', aborting". Progress! Now I was getting the error on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53865612/trouble-installing-dbdmysql-under-macos-mojave). I fixed this error by:

- Verifying that my problem is indeed from missing linkage flags.
- Run `mysql_config`
- This returns something like: --libs [L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -l]
- Note that the "-l" at the end has nothing after it, which is incorrect.
- Edit `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/bin/mysql_config line #114`
- Change `libs="$libs -l"`  to `libs="$libs -lmysqlclient"`
- Verify that it worked: `mysql_config`
- This should return something like: --libs [L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -lmysqlclient]
- Again do `cpanm install DBD::mysql`
- This time it works!!!
- Be wary: We're not installing the lib for SSL connections which will [probably cause cryptic problems](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod#ENCRYPTED-CONNECTIONS-via-SSL) later.

This got DBD::mysql installed successfully for me. I do think I'm going to have to go back and add some more linkage flags.

Comment: What happens to the databases installed via `mysql` when you run `brew unlink mysql $$ brew install mysql-connector-c`??  I gave up because I don't wanna mess up my *AMP stack.

Comment: I don't know, but caution seems wise. You should certainly [back up](http://osxdaily.com/2017/01/19/export-import-all-mysql-databases/) your DB somewhere if you care about whats in it. Also, dunno if this is useful, but this ended up being such a pain I switched to using Python for accessing MySQL.

Answer (score 14):

1. show `mysql_config` path by `which mysql_config`

   > eg: /usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin/mysql_config
2. show openssl lib path by `which openssl`. note: if it's a symbol in `/usr/local/bin/openssl`, you can type `ls -ld /usr/local/bin/openssl` to show real path

   > eg: if it's `/usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl`, 
   >   then you can insert `-L/usr/local/openssl/lib/` for searching `crypto` and `ssl` libs
3. edit `mysql_config` file and insert path of openssl lib(line #114)

   > eg: `libs=$libs -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib`

   [image: insert path of openssl lib]
   4.type `cpan install DBD::mysql` , success.

Comment: This worked for me, with one tweak. I found the openssl lib path in the output from `brew info openssl` not `which openssl`, because Homebrew installs it as keg-only.

Comment: I've used this fix loads of times, and have now opened [an issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/72333) on homebrew-core that references this comment, so hopefully I'll never to use it again!

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon this AGAIN, and after none of the answers worked, this one helped right away:

```sh
PATH="$(brew --prefix mysql-client)/bin:$PATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
cpanm DBD::mysql
```

Credit goes to https://blog.mitsuto.com/macos-mojave-perl-dbd-mysql

Comment: This fixed it for me too, on Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: You sir, are my new hero. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the link given in @Benny K answer as the commands he gave didn't worked for me and simply executed the below command and it worked

```html
cpanm DBD::mysql --configure-args="--libs='-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient'"
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error and while poking around trying to figure it out I added -I/usr/local/mysql/include to the perl makefile.pl command. This didn't work but like a goat i tried again and then it came up with an Xcode agreement form that I had to read and abide by. Longer story i upgraded an older macbook pro to el capitan then had to install Xcode 6.3 last week. I'd forgotten about the newer Xcode. Anyway, the end result was a successful install once i'd agreed to the Xcode usage

Comment: thanks for the reply Mike, still no joy for me
perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

 cflags        (mysql_config) = -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.9/include
  embedded      (guessed     ) =
  ldflags       (guessed     ) =
  libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.9/lib -l
  mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
  
Checking if libs are available for compiling...
Can't link/include C library '', aborting.