# Trouble installing DBD::mysql under macOS Mojave

Tags: perl, macos-mojave, dbd

Can't install DBD::mysql under macOS Mojave with perl v5.18.2
MySQL Community Server 8.0.13 is installed from DMG from the official site.

Here is the installation log via cpan:

```
Checking if libs are available for compiling...
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dmitry/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.049-B01C7C/assertliblxuNN4_E
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dmitry/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.049-B01C7C/assertliba7FpHZin
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/dmitry/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.049-B01C7C/assertlibeWospvnt
  Reason: image not found
wrong result: 'mysqlclient', 'ssl', 'crypto'
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.049.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
```

Swears at the lack of libraries, although they are:

```
dmitry@iMac-Dmitrij:~$ ls -la /usr/local/mysql/lib/*.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1985924  7 окт 13:14 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       21 18 дек 23:35 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libcrypto.dylib -> libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  5844880  7 окт 15:28 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       23 18 дек 23:35 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib -> libmysqlclient.21.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   540768  7 окт 15:28 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlharness.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       23 18 дек 23:35 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlharness.dylib -> libmysqlharness.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  6861328  7 окт 15:28 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlrouter.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       22 18 дек 23:35 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlrouter.dylib -> libmysqlrouter.1.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   429768  7 окт 13:14 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       18 18 дек 23:35 /usr/local/mysql/lib/libssl.dylib -> libssl.1.0.0.dyli
```

What do you advise ?

Comment: You probably need to tell it where the libraries are

Comment: @ChrisTurner, At the configuration stage, mysql_config tells where the libraries are located: libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto

Comment: I can assume that you need to install MySQL headers and libraries and point to this directory your Makefile.pl script (I see libmysqld-libs option there)

Comment: Have you tried installing the libraries locally with Carton? (This usually incurs a non-trivial amount of overhead to set up the first time, but I've found it helps later on.)

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem installing DBD::mysql on Mojave 10.14.  Followed the instructions in this link: 
   https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/commit/00806bc46fe23a862a325d19cba07c239b401def

first try

```
brew install openssl mysql-connector-c
```

this installs but running

```
cpan install DBD::mysql
```

fails because the -l file designation is empty shown in the output line:

`libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/lib -l`

editing the

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11/bin/mysql_config line #114
```

and change

```
libs="$libs -l"  to libs="$libs -lmysqlclient"
```

then run:

```
cpan install DBD::mysql
```

is joy.