# unable to connect mysql 5.8 using perl5.18 on macOS Mojave version 10.14.6

Tags: mysql, macos, perl

I want to connect the `MySQL` client by using below `perl5.18` script on `macOS`.

File name: `db.pl`

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "test";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "qawseder123";

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test
                       (first_name, last_name, sex, age)
                         values
                       ('john', 'poul', 1, 30)");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->finish();
$dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```

When I execute **`perl db.pl`**, it gives below error.

> install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::mysql module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at (eval 4) line 3.
>   Perhaps the DBD::mysql perl module hasn't been fully installed,
>   or perhaps the capitalisation of 'mysql' isn't right.
>   Available drivers: DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, Mem, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge.
>    at db.pl line 12.

To resolve above error below commands are executed.

**`perl -MCPAN -e shell`**

**`install DBD::mysql`**

But it gives below error when I execute **`install DBD::mysql`**.

> wrong result: 'mysqlclient', 'ssl', 'crypto'
>   Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
>   'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
>     DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz
>     /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
>   Running make test
>     Make had some problems, won't test
>   Running make install
>     Make had some problems, won't install
>   Failed during this command:
>    DVEEDEN/DBD-mysql-4.050.tar.gz               : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 512.

Would you guide me?

Comment: The pertinent bit is `wrong result: 'mysqlclient', 'ssl', 'crypto'` (and maybe things that came before that). Not sure what produces that or what it means. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/53865612/589924.

Comment: Also found this: https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/issues/161#issuecomment-449962061

Comment: This might be the correct solution: https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/issues/161#issuecomment-531742015